# Two Column R Dataframe to Named LIst

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am trying to convert a two-column dataframe to a named list. There are several solutions on StackOverflow where every value in the first column becomes the 'name', but I am looking to collapse the values in column 2 into common values in column 1.

For example, the list should look like the following:

```
# Create a Named list of keywords associated with each file. 
fileKeywords <- list(fooBar.R = c("A","B","C"),
                 driver.R = c("A","F","G"))
```

Where I can retrieve all keywords for "fooBar.R" using:

```
# Get the keywords for a named file
fileKeywords[["fooBar.R"]]
```

My data frame looks like:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
file        keyWord
'fooBar.R'  'A'
'fooBar.R'  'B'
'fooBar.R'  'C'
'driver.R'  'A'
'driver.R'  'F'
'driver.R'  'G'
")
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution that I am missing.

Comment: `split(df$keyWord, df$file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `unstack`:

```
as.list(unstack(rev(df)))

$driver.R
[1] "A" "F" "G"

$fooBar.R
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

This is equivalent to `as.list(unstack(df, keyWord~file))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stack` in `base R`

```
stack(fileKeywords)[2:1]
```

---

if it is the opposite, then we can do

```
with(df, tapply(keyWord, file, FUN = I))
```

-output

```
#$driver.R
#[1] "A" "F" "G"

#$fooBar.R
#[1] "A" "B" "C"
```